# Cannot genetrate java client for file upload webservice

Tags: web-services, file-upload, cxf, jax-rs

I have a simple file upload web service as a small part of my project.

This is what I have done so far on the server side :

```
    @POST
@Path("/file")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(List<Attachment> attachments,@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Got an attachment!");
    for(Attachment attr : attachments) {
        DataHandler handler = attr.getDataHandler();
        try {
            InputStream stream = handler.getInputStream();
            MultivaluedMap map = attr.getHeaders();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/yashdosi/s/" + getFileName(map)));    //getFileName is a seperate private function..

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            stream.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return Response.ok("file uploaded").build();
}
```

It works perfectly well when requests come from html forms...when I try to send a request from a java client it simply doesnt work..!!

Any ideas about on creating a java client for this code..

Here is the code I tried with...maybe there is a simple error in this code but..I dont see it...also as I said this code simple wont work...no errors or anything else....when I tried printing something on the server console to see if the service is invoked...it did NOT print anything..so I think I am unable to contact the service for some reason...

```
    public static void uploadPhoto() 
{
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/fileupload-ws/services/postdata";
    String output = null;
    PostMethod mPost = new PostMethod(url);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    try 
    {
        File imageFile = new File("/home/yashdosi/1.jpg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
        byte[] encodedImage = Base64.encodeBase64(baos.toByteArray());

        String data = " " + " " + "" + "image/jpeg" + " " + "" + new String(encodedImage) + " " + "";

        mPost.setRequestBody(data);
        mPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        client.executeMethod( mPost );
        output = mPost.getResponseBodyAsString( );
        mPost.releaseConnection( );
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: It cannot "simply not work". What happens? What's the response code? Do you get any error message? My guess is you're missing some request headers or perhaps the content type. Show us your client code.

Comment: @Tom - I edited the question and added the client code...maybe now you can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a client working!!

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/fileupload-ws/services/postdata");

        FileBody img = new FileBody(new File("/home/yashdosi/1.jpg"));
        FileBody html = new FileBody(new File("/home/yashdosi/hotmail.html"));

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("image", img);
        reqEntity.addPart("html", html);

        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try { httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
```